# Spring MVC: an alternative to Thymeleaf and including page as layouts

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In ASP.Net MVC, dealing with layouts is rather easy as the framework takes care of the whole thing in the background and renders the html body and user defined section where they should go. For instance:

```
<div class="com-md-12">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

This is while, I've been doing this so far in Spring MVC by creating two jsp pages (i.e. Header and Footer) and including both as layouts in my partial jsp pages. On the other hand, I have found that `Thymeleaf` is unnecessarily complicated and I believe that the include page method is both old and obsolete.

What is the best and most efficient (Standard according to the Spring Framework) way to create and use layouts?

Answer (score 0):

Well actually my favorite techonology is [Apache tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/framework) 
It implements the [Composite View](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compositeview-137722.html) pattern and so far I never had problems